# Let $A\in M_n(\mathbb{R})$. Show that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \bigg( I + \frac{A}{n}\bigg)^n = e^A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-exponential

I used the binomial theorem and wrote 
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \bigg( I + \frac{A}{n} \bigg)^n =\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} \left(\frac{A}{n} \right)^{k}  $$
And so I tried to compare this sum with $$\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \frac{A^i}{i!}$$ but I couldn't see a clear way to do it.

Any hints?

Comment: Have you looked up the proof for $A$ a $1\times 1$ matrix - that is a real number?

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't seem to be  an immediate generalization since the case $1 \times 1$ compares both sequences using $\leq$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: prove the result for the complex field.  It is true for diagonalizable matrices. Since diagonalizable matrices are dense conclude.